# Build failed while installing angular-cli in Windows 7 - Failed at node-sass postinstall

Tags: windows-7, angular-cli, node-sass

I am trying to install angular-cli in Windows 7. But there is an error -

```
Failed at node-sass@3.10.1 post install script 'node scripts/build.js'.
```

I also get the below error.

```
Toolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1
was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK 
version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and 
selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
```

Has anyone faced this kind of issue while installing angular-cli in windows 7? Please help to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is fixed in angular-cli. Now I am able to install and use it with Windows 7. Marking it as answered.